# Format list of file from git diff

Tags: bash, git

I'm using git diff with git archive to archive a given list of files.

```
git archive --prefix="files/" --format=tar.gz --output="/home/me/archives/sources-project-v1.0.0-v2.2.3.tar.gz" "v2.2.3" $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d "v1.0.0" "v2.2.3")
```

But i am getting the error

> error: unknown switch `.'
>   usage: git archive []  [...]

I am trying to get why, this error is impossible solve using google...
So, I extracted the given list from git diff and I saw that some files have in their name and the output is not escaped.

Do you known how to solve this error ?
Or how to escape list of files given by git diff ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `git archive ... v2.2.3 --  $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d "v1.0.0" "v2.2.3")`, the relevant detail being the `--` before the list of files.

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! It seems good for the error but files with space in name are always returning an error "fatal: pathspec 'incomplete/path/to' did not match any files"